# How to avoid auto-updating of MongoDB ObjectIds after restoring the dump using mongorestore command?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to restore my database dump using mongorestore command. And got to know that some ObjectIds are updating automatically after restoring and am facing data dependency issues with that. Does ObjectIds updates itself while restoring? If yes, is there any alternative to stop that issue?

Comment: What do you mean Normally @SaurabhAgrawal? I have never faced that kind of issue.

Comment: That should not be happening normally. Please check the indexes in the collection you're importing, there might be a mismatch in data type of import data and defined indexes. Corrected the typo @sharankenam. :)